# Breakdown Google Billing by could function / app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-billing

Is it possible to break down cloud billing by cloud function and app engine?

We have had a spike in cost for App Engine and also Cloud Functions.

The current breakdown just states `Frontend Instances Sydney` and could functions its `CPU Time (tier 1)`.

What we need is to know which app engine instance, and which cloud function instance has caused the increase.

thanks!

Comment: Add labels to your instances. Export the billing data to BigQuery. Run queries based on labels.

Comment: will that work retrospectivly?

Comment: No, only for data after you enable exporting.

Comment: Hi @nzmattman, Could you please check this [blog](https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-cloud-platform-resource-labeling-best-practices-66fded7ba57) and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks @MarcAnthonyB